# compute.beta.regionAutoscaler error flask app giving an error when deployed on google cloud

Tags: flask, gcloud

P.s. this is a flask python3 app
I have tested this app on local host and it works well, but when I try to deploy this app to the google cloud all I get is an error, which I can't seem to fix, I have tried even giving the compute engine and app engine the admin permission in iAM panel, but still no success, please help.

i have the code on github https://github.com/ManinderSinghAjimal/flask-test-app-1.git

The error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/flask-1-281017/regions/asia-south1/operations/047ccf3a-d10b-446c-98fa-cf8b0030f076 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-06-22T13:46:06.604Z15036.ow.0: Deployment Manager operation flask-1-281017/operation-1592833567657-5a8ac76fc8c66-e121f85c-538636c0 errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20200622t191524/resources/aef-default-20200622t191524"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"message\":\"The caller does not have permission\",\"status\":\"PERMISSION_DENIED\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/flask-1-281017/regions/asia-south1/autoscalers\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
]
```

this actually makes no sense to me, so if anyone can suggest something, it will be really helpful.

Comment: I understand that you are using App Engine Flexible, just to discard is not a problem with your instance could you try to follow this document? just the simple Hello World example. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/quickstart#deploy_and_run_hello_world_on_app_engine

Comment: But I already tried a single file, hello world in python and it works, only this error arises when I try to deploy an app with more functionality, even in cloud console this app work, just not deploying for some reason

Comment: could you try to deploy with the --verbosity flag and share the complete trace?  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to resources in the zone that your project is located (some time gcp resources get low in some zones and regions and it is difficult to deploy an app in that zone/region).You could try out different zones/regions for example instead asia-south1 you can try with asia-northeast3

Comment: I actually made changes to app.yaml file, and delete the  "env: flex" from it, the app deployed but now it says 502 error ngix.

Comment: Until I know that field is necessary on your project at least you are using App Engine Standard environment, in order to discard a possible issue with your code I really recommend you try to deploy in another region, please let me know you results, also you can check this document too: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/troubleshooting#resource_errors_code_resource_error

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#general

Comment: I recently dropped the whole project and restarted from scratch, this is the repo for the new app, but when I deploy this the homepage is delivered well, but when I try to navigate to another page it just gives an error.(  Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.     )   and env: is standard as flex isn't working for me in any way. https://github.com

Comment: I understand, seems like this issue is more related to code, I suggest you close this question and open another related to your actual scenario, check this document https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask